# Does Encode::encode modify/delete the original string?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

The documentation of [`Encode::encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode#encode) says:

> **encode**
>
> *$octets  = encode(ENCODING, STRING[, CHECK])* Encodes the scalar value
>   STRING from Perl's internal form into ENCODING and returns a sequence
>   of octets.

Here is a test script:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );

use Encode qw(encode);

my $str = 'æ';
say "str = '$str'";
my $str2 = encode('UTF-8', $str, Encode::FB_CROAK);
say "str = '$str'";
```

The output is:

```
str = 'æ'
str = ''
```

Why is `$str` erased after calling `encode`? Is this to be expected?

Comment: It seems like a bug. Use `encode('UTF-8', "$str", Encode:::FB_CROAK)` as a workaround.

Comment: Of course UTF8 encoding is popular, so popular that they named a subroutine specifically for it.  You can call without the check: `encode_utf8($str)`

Comment: I think this answers the question http://stackoverflow.com/a/29843396/198183

Comment: @sid_com Thanks, that would be the answer. So you could mark this question as duplicate..

Comment: @HåkonHægland not an exact duplicate.  Despite them being close in concept and their problem being the same, the other question asked specifically for a true check value.  This question has a better demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If the Encode::LEAVE_SRC bit is not set but CHECK is set, then the source string to encode() or decode() will be overwritten in place. If you're not interested in this, then bitwise-OR it with the bitmask."

Quote from the [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) documentation.